# How to disable the cache in cordova android app

Tags: android, cordova, caching, cordova-3

I had used the Cordova 3.6.3 version for building my android app and i wnat to disable the caching of URL in cordova webview , I am using the default cordova project for that purpose and using the index.html file.
I tried this but it is crashing my app

```
public class MyClass extends CordovaActivity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mwebview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.appView);
    WebSettings ws=mwebview.getSettings();
    ws.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    ws.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may find this helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221395/turn-off-caching-on-android-for-webapps

Comment: I tried this but I am not able to find the appView.getSettings() in my code

Comment: I had shared the code in my post

Answer (score 7):

**cordova-disable-http-cache**

Cordova plugin to completely disable caching of HTTP requests and responses.

Just type this command in your Cordova CLI:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-disable-http-cache
```

This will fetch plugin "cordova-disable-http-cache" via npm and install "cordova-disable-http-cache" for android.

It solved my problem with disabling cache in my application.
My cordova version is 6.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

Cordova (due to running on top of webview) respects the nocache header, if you're able to set that in your server it should give you the same result. Plus you can control the use of the cache itself through expirations and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the following plugin :

https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-cache

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady);
function onDeviceReady() {
    var success = function(status) {
        alert('Message: ' + status);
    }
    var error = function(status) {
        alert('Error: ' + status);
    }
    window.cache.clear( success, error );
}
```

This will clear the cache of your application everytime you launch it.

You can comment alerts in the callbacks.

Comment: But I want to disable the creation of cache

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: https://github.com/wongatech/cordova-disable-nsurl-cache

Comment: But this is for IOS. i need it for android

Comment: It might be a bit late, but I created a Cordova plugin for this: https://github.com/koenoe/cordova-disable-http-cache

Answer (score 0):

[hdezela's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38222232/2540235) answer worked for me, so I'm providing my working **PHP solution** below:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
```

Put this code at the top of your server-side code, close your emulator then *Wipe Data* from it using the *AVD Manager*, then rerun your application.